# Which scripts are required for Bootstrap Navbar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I was creating a custom build of Bootstrap using the [Customize](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) feature on the Bootstrap website. All I want are the grids, responsive utilities, and the collapsable navbar.

I toggled everything to deselected, then selected **Grid System**, **Responsive utilities**, and **Navbar**. When you select **Navbar** it automatically selects **Forms** and **Navs**, but does not select any of the jQuery Plugins.

When you click **Compile and Download** it churns out the CSS files, but there are no JavaScript files.

Do you know which jQuery plug-ins need to be included for the Bootstrap Navbars to function properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

> Requires JavaScript plugin
>
> If JavaScript is disabled and the viewport is narrow enough that the
>   navbar collapses, it will be impossible to expand the navbar and view
>   the content within the .navbar-collapse.
>
> The responsive navbar requires the [collapse plugin](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse) to be included in
>   your version of Bootstrap.

Comment: Grr... I looked right at that in the documentation and completely passed over the "collapse plugin" :(

Comment: Well, sometimes you overlook what’s right in front of your eyes :-)

Comment: Interestingly, that wasn't all that was required. The navbars wouldn't work with only those components and the Collapse plugin. I got frustrated and threw the kitchen sink at it: included all the components and plugins. Working now, but the site is bloated with a bunch of other stuff I won't use.

Comment: The Collapse plugin requires the Transitions plugin as well (as it states in the description of the Collapse plugin itself) … not all those requirements are resolved correctly by the customizer. Sometimes with Bootstrap, you need to look at the documentation very closely to figure out what’s essential for certain combinations of components.

Answer (score 0):

When you modify css and download, it does not make any changes in the jquery files. You can download the default jquery from their [website](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/).